# Linker issues with dmd and Derelict in Linux: Ld can't find .a files

Tags: linker, dmd

I am trying to write a test program in D using Derelict2 bindings. Here is my code:

```
import std.stdio;
import derelict.sfml.audio;

pragma(lib, "/home/ryan/Derelict2/lib/libDerelictSFMLAudio.a");
pragma(lib, "/home/ryan/Derelict2/lib/libDerelictUtil.a");


void main(){
  DerelictSFMLAudio.load();
}
```

All of derelict's .di files are in dmd's default import directory, so I am under the impression that the following command should compile and link my program.

```
dmd test.d -L-lDerelictSFML -L-lDerelictUtil -L-ldl
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lDerelictSFML
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lDerelictUtil
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
--- errorlevel 1
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

A little off topic but a concern as well:

What does the -ldl flag do? I know it's needed for a successful link but I'm not sure how and it's not in the ld manual.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the library location (e.g. -L-L/usr/lib/dmd) to dmd as well:

```
dmd test.d -I/usr/include/d -L-L/usr/lib/dmd -L-lDerelictSFML -L-lDerelictUtil -L-ldl
```

`-ldl` stands for libdl which is a library that grants your program the ability to link dynamically to libraries.